# hilti PX 10 TRANSPOINTER working principle

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetics, magnetometer

Sorry to ask this here. But I really got wondered what is this product's working principle. Anybody share what would be the core  idea behind this product PX 10 TRANSPOINTER from hilti.

[Click here to find the product official page](https://www.hilti.com/measuring-systems/detection-systems/r3538)

Answer (score 1):

A low RF induction field is created by the torroid in the sender.

The receiver torroid being PLL tuned to same frequency detects strongest signal when both are parallel and concentric.

Thus you can determine ideal location for drilling on hard to get side with sender and locate center on the easy side. Range is given as 2" to 4ft.

- parallel surfaces are essential with greater distance and may be influenced by iron near/between the path loss.